# How to use attr_writer for module methods?

Tags: ruby

Here is my module:

```
module A
  def self.data=(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
```

I want to use `attr_writer` instead. Is it possible in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `attr_writer` inside the module's singleton class.

```
module A
  class << self; attr_writer :data; end
end
```